# Synchronize multiple nav-tabs with multiple nav-bars in Boostrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm building a tool to help some co-workers examine and compare information.
I want this information to be shown in the same manner for each order is shown and since there are a lot of "groups" of information for each order I have built nav-tabs to switch between each information group.
I would however like the nav tab selector-bar for all selectors to be updated, not just the one the user clicked.

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <div class="container">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <div class='col-md-12'>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-12' style='margin-top: -50px;'>
            <ul class='nav nav-pills'>
              <li class='active'><a data-toggle='tab' href='.TabA'>Tab A</a>

              </li>
              <li><a data-toggle='tab' href='.TabB'>Tab B</a>

              </li>
              <li><a data-toggle='tab' href='.TabC'>Tab C</a>

              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id='TabA1' class='tab-pane fade in active TabA'>
          <div class='row'>aaaaaaaa11111111111</div>
        </div>
        <div id='TabB1' class='tab-pane fade TabB'>
          <div class='row'>bbbbbbb11111111</div>
        </div>
        <div id='TabC1' class='tab-pane fade TabC'>
          <div class='row'>cccccccccc1111111</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <div class='col-md-12'>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-12' style='margin-top: -50px;'>
            <ul class='nav nav-pills'>
              <li class='active'><a data-toggle='tab' href='.TabA'>Tab A</a>

              </li>
              <li><a data-toggle='tab' href='.TabB'>Tab B</a>

              </li>
              <li><a data-toggle='tab' href='.TabC'>Tab C</a>

              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id='TabA2' class='tab-pane fade in active TabA'>
          <div class='row'>aaaaaaaa22222222</div>
        </div>
        <div id='TabB2' class='tab-pane fade TabB'>
          <div class='row'>bbbbbbb222222222</div>
        </div>
        <div id='TabC2' class='tab-pane fade TabC'>
          <div class='row'>cccccccccc2222222</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

So if you click on any of the selector bar "buttons" the info tab for both changes correctly, but the selector of the one I didn't click won't change. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `href` value and the tab in each `class`. Difficult to explain: check my solution

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <div class="container">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <div class='col-md-12'>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-12' style='margin-top: -50px;'>
            <ul class='nav nav-pills'>
              <li class='active'><a data-toggle='tab' href='.TabA1'>Tab A</a> <!--CHANGE HREF-->

              </li>
              <li><a data-toggle='tab' href='.TabB1'>Tab B</a>

              </li>
              <li><a data-toggle='tab' href='.TabC1'>Tab C</a>

              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id='TabA1' class='tab-pane fade in active TabA1'> <!--PUT SAME VALUE AS IN HREF-->
          <div class='row'>aaaaaaaa11111111111</div>
        </div>
        <div id='TabB1' class='tab-pane fade TabB1'>
          <div class='row'>bbbbbbb11111111</div>
        </div>
        <div id='TabC1' class='tab-pane fade TabC1'>
          <div class='row'>cccccccccc1111111</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <div class='col-md-12'>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-12' style='margin-top: -50px;'>
            <ul class='nav nav-pills'>
              <li class='active'><a data-toggle='tab' href='.TabA2'>Tab A</a>

              </li>
              <li><a data-toggle='tab' href='.TabB2'>Tab B</a>

              </li>
              <li><a data-toggle='tab' href='.TabC2'>Tab C</a>

              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id='TabA2' class='tab-pane fade in active TabA2'>
          <div class='row'>aaaaaaaa22222222</div>
        </div>
        <div id='TabB2' class='tab-pane fade TabB2'>
          <div class='row'>bbbbbbb222222222</div>
        </div>
        <div id='TabC2' class='tab-pane fade TabC2'>
          <div class='row'>cccccccccc2222222</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid what you have done is to create two completely separate nav-tabs instead of making them synchronized. Still grateful for your effort!

Comment: Oh sorry, yes I misunderstood. I don't have correctly understood  the "synchronised" aspect because the first Tab has "aa1", "bb1" and "cc1" and the second the same 3 texts but 2 instead of 1